# push data from webservice to android app: C2DM

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm, server-push

I have a use case where I need to send some information from my webservice to an Android App. I just got to know about C2DM which is used for such use cases (correct me if I am wrong).

Does someone know how much latency one can expect while using this service? In my use case, I want the message to be sent from the webservice to the phone within 1-2 sec.

Has someone used C2DM and have an idea of how much is the average message delay? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should now move to GCM : -

> GCM [check it here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

If you are going to start with any **messaging or push notification functionality**  then **avoid C2DM** as **more support would be given to GCM (google cloud messaging)**. Also it has simpler API and more reliability for notification delivery.

> Reliability & Delay in messaging [check here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html)

**Just a thought** :

> Other option would be to poll data after certain interval of time and
>   that time would obviously be more then 5 seconds or so **{ your choice
>   }**. With that you will make users a bit reluctant as data connection
>   would be always needed and battery would be consumed more. So these things would be replenished by GCM services. But as far as message delivery is concerned its not **for sure reliable**.

Comment: what about the delay ? it would be nice to know, if you know

Comment: well for me it takes a delay of `5 seconds when it is maximum delay`.

Comment: Thanks folks! In my use case, I cannot afford a delay more than 2 sec.

Comment: Then probably you will just have to make a poll every second or two, or perhaps there's an "urgent" option in GCM

Comment: Well I would say you should give it a try in a sample app. And check how much delays are you getting because other use cases are not proper.